# php compression css and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, css, compression

I would like to copress my JavaScript and CSS files and I use a PHP file with the following code:

```
// compression.php
ob_start ( 'ob_gzhandler' );

$content = file_get_contents ( $_GET [ 'path' ] );
$extension = strtolower ( substr ( strrchr ( $_GET [ 'path' ], "." ), 1 ) );
header ( "Content-Type:" . ( $extension == 'css' ? 'text/css' : 'text/javascript' ) );
header ( "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header ( "Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
echo $content;
```

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="compression.php?path=../assets/css/jquery-ui.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="compression.php?path=../assets/js/jquery.min.js">
```

Is this good way or not?

Comment: "...this question will likely solicit **opinion**, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion." If you need a code review, there is a [site for that](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: when no answer was helpful why should i accept any answer!????

Comment: If no answer was helpful, you may be [asking the wrong questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).

Comment: it's funny man!maybe no one can't help me about it!you mean all answer in this site is helpful ?

Comment: You know, you may be right. Maybe no one can help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it **definitely** is not.

What about `compression.php?path=compression.php`? One could view **all** your PHP and server files which is an severe security issue.

What's more, the server will spend a lot of its power to compressing at each page request.

Why not just minify your code and save it statically instead. It will be much more effective.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compress your JS:

Use [packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/), with `Shrink variables` checked.

To compress the CSS:

Use [Clean CSS](http://www.cleancss.com/?lang=en), with `Sort Properties`, and `Remove last ;` checked.